# Tomcat Context initialization failed

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have project with two modules: 1) Midtier & 2) webapp.

My mid-tier has beans configuration file that does the component scan for the specified packages to load beans. One of such class I have created is ApplicationContextUtils which extends ApplicationContextAware interface which is in the jar SPRING-CONTEXT. (Yes I have tagged the class ApplicationContextUtils with annotation @Component). The pom of this project has declared spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE as the dependent jar & I can see it in the maven dependencies. I tested this class alone by running a test which loads all the beans & it ran well.

Now, moving onto webapp, webapp's pom describes the midtier as its dependency. I can see this mid-tier project is listed as maven dependency in webapps. Deploying this project from eclipse to Tomcat I got following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.jms.testjms.ApplicationContextUtils] for bean with name 'applicationContextUtils' defined in file [F:\Projects\ActiveMQ\JMSProject\target\classes\com\jms\testjms\ApplicationContextUtils.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware
(& lot of error chains ..)
```

The only reasoning I can get is the jar spring-context is not in the class path. But, when I checked in the WEB-INF/lib, of course there is the jar spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE which is the source for interface ApplicationContextAware. I am not sure why spring cannot find this interface.

I am using spring 3.2.4. My web.xml is using ContextLoaderListener for loading resources during the start up. The project is build using maven.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

POM from mid-tier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.jms.test</groupId>
<artifactId>JmsTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Spring Utility</name>
<url>http://www.springframework.org</url>
<description>
    <![CDATA[
  This project is a minimal jar utility with Spring configuration.
]]>
</description>
<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
</properties>   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

pom from webapp:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>JmsProtoWebApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>JMSWebApp</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>JMSWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
    <spring.framework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.37</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jms.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>JmsTest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies> 

  <build>
    <finalName>JMSWebApp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

project structure & deployment assembly:
http://imgur.com/zydcqSm

Comment: Please post your `pom` and possibly an image of your project structure in eclipse.

Comment: I have updated the post with pom from mid-tier & webapp. Included is the link for project structure & deployment assembly

Comment: you need to deploy your spring jars to tomcat also.

Comment: @happymeal Yes it is there. Here is list of jars in WEB-INF/lib [link](http://i.imgur.com/fafIXAm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your webapp application have [activemq-spring:5.8.0] dependency, which include also [org.springframework:stuff:3.1.3.RELEASE].

As you include [org.springframework:stuff:3.2.4.RELEASE], you may have some conflict in your classpath.

You should use  in you pom depdendency while including [activemq-spring] to drop unwanted spring.